# Audio sample amplitude level at each sample point

Tags: c++, audio, core-audio

I'm trying to get audio into memory, and then have a loop, check every sample and return the amplitude value at every sample point in the audio, and send that information to an array.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How do you get sample amplitude from audio stored in a buffer ?

Comment: It depends on format in which the audio is stored.

Comment: Are you talking on the pointer level or the file type? if so what about Wav files?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Core Audio API Tutorial, section Override the Process Method](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitProgrammingGuide/Tutorial-BuildingASimpleEffectUnitWithAGenericView/Tutorial-BuildingASimpleEffectUnitWithAGenericView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003278-CH5-SW57)?  If so, show what code you have tried in your question.  If not, the tutorial is probably the place to start, and that section shows how to examine the samples element by element.